# While loop not running after function

Tags: php, function, while-loop

I have a while loop that checks my database for notifications with a status of 1. It then sends a notification to OneSignal.com's API so the user will get the notification.

The problem is, I'm trying to run the script so that it processes all records with a status of 1 as it makes the while loop, but once I include the function for OneSignal the while loop stops after processing only one record.

I cant figure it out, I tried moving things around, and when I put the send message function outside the while loop, the php variables for the user ID don't get passed to it?

What should I do?

```
<?php

require('connection.inc.php');


$notification = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT *, t1.id AS NotifID FROM notification AS t1 LEFT JOIN user AS t2 ON t1.action_user_id = t2.id WHERE status = '1' ORDER BY time_updated DESC") or die(mysql_error());


//GET NOTIFCATION RECORD
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($notification)) {
    $notificationID      = $row['NotifID'];
    $type                = $row['notification_type'];
    $action_user_id      = $row['action_user_id'];
    $action_user_name    = $row['name'];
    $action_user_profile = empty($row['profile_image']) ? '/instachurch/images/profile/profile.png' : '/instachurch/' . $row['profile_image'];
    $time                = $row['time_updated'];
    $post_id             = $row['post_id'];
    $notify_user_id      = $row['notify_user_id'];
    
    
    // GET NOTIFY USER INFO
    $GetUserName = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = $notify_user_id ") or die(mysql_error());
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($GetUserName)) {
        $username        = $row['name'];
        $userMob         = $row['mob'];
        $userHash        = $row['hash'];
        $OneSignalPushID = $row['id'];
        
        
        
        if ($type == "post_liked")
            $message = $action_user_name . " liked your post.";
        else if ($type == "post_comment")
            $message = $action_user_name . " commented on your post.";
        else if ($type == "post_comment_reply")
            $message = $action_user_name . " replied to your comment.";
        else if ($type == "post_answer")
            $message = $action_user_name . " answered to your question.";
        else if ($type == "follow_user")
            $message = $action_user_name . " started following you.";
        else if ($type == "discussion_topic_comment")
            $message = $action_user_name . " commented on your forum topic.";
        else if ($type == "timeline_mention")
            $message = $action_user_name . " mentioned you in a comment.";
        else if ($type == "school_lesson_mention" || $type == "school_discussion_mention")
            $message = $action_user_name . " mentioned you in a comment on discussion.";
        
        
        
        if ($type == "post_comment" || $type == "post_liked" || $type == "post_comment_reply" || $type == "post_answer" || $type == "timeline_mention")
            $link = "http://www.gypsychristiannetwork.com/instachurch/post.php?post_id=" . $post_id . '&hash=' . $userHash;
        else if ($type == "follow_user")
            $link = "http://www.gypsychristiannetwork.com/instachurch/users.php?id=" . $action_user_id . '&hash=' . $userHash;
        else if ($type == "discussion_topic_comment")
            $link = "http://www.gypsychristiannetwork.com/tgcm/school/account.php?q=24&topic=" . $post_id . '&hash=' . $userHash;
        else if ($type == "school_lesson_mention")
            $link = "http://www.gypsychristiannetwork.com/tgcm/school/account.php?q=11&qid=" . $post_id . '&hash=' . $userHash;
        else if ($type == "school_discussion_mention")
            $link = "http://www.gypsychristiannetwork.com/tgcm/school/account.php?q=24&topic=" . $post_id . '&hash=' . $userHash;
        
        
    }
    
    $q3 = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE `notification` SET `status` = '2' WHERE `id` = '$notificationID'");
    echo $notificationID . ':' . $message;
    
    // echo $link;
    $userPushID = $OneSignalPushID;
    //  echo $userPushID.'<BR><P>';
    $heading    = 'Check your Notifications';
    
    $content = array(
        "en" => $message
    );
    
    $heading = array(
        "en" => $heading
    );
    
    
    $fields = array(
        'app_id' => "APPID",
        'include_external_user_ids' => array(
            "$userPushID"
        ),
        'channel_for_external_user_ids' => 'push',
        'data' => array(
            "foo" => "bar"
        ),
        'contents' => $content,
        'headings' => $heading,
        'url' => $link
    );
    
    $fields = json_encode($fields);
    print("\nJSON sent:\n");
    print($fields);
    
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://onesignal.com/api/v1/notifications");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
        'Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8',
        'Authorization: Basic APPSECRET'
    ));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    
    return $response;
    
    
    $response               = sendMessage();
    $return["allresponses"] = $response;
    $return                 = json_encode($return);
    
    print("\n\nJSON received:\n");
    print($return);
    print("\n");
    
    
    
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

There seems to be a 'return $response' line near the bottom, which would probably break the while{}. Try removing that, or maybe rewrite that part

Comment: The return will *definitely* break a loop.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if it were me, I would try to rework this first so there are fewer nested `while` loops. In this case, you can do it fairly simply, by iterating through the results (as you're doing) and pushing them to an array outside the function, like so:

```
 $ary = array();

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($yourQueryResults, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
    {
        array_push($ary, array($row['valueYouIntendToUseLater']));
    }
```

Then you can run the interior `while` on the resulting array, like

```
    foreach($element in $ary){
        while.....etc
    }
```

And so on. You get the drill. While this format is certainly not necessary, it does make debugging easier in my experience. As @Jelmer pointed out, the reason this `while` function is biting the dust is because you're calling `return` in it, which breaks the loop, as is its purpose.